# FormData type coercion

Tags: typescript

I've got a form I made, and I'm working on wiring up the submit event.

Here's what I'm doing right now to convert my form data entries to `RegisterFormFields`:

```
const data = new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement);

const inputValues = Object.fromEntries(data.entries()) as unknown as RegisterFormFields;

console.log(inputValues);
```

Is there a better way than using `unknown` to my type?

Answer (score 0):

This certainly is a way to do it, but it does not give you any guarantees and type safety from TypeScript - It is up to you to ensure that the types are correct.

I would say one of the best approaches is to use TypeScript's [Type Predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for such cases.

If it basically a function in which you validate you input data and only then assign a type.

```
const data = new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement);

const inputValues = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());

function validFormData(inputValues: {[k: string]: FormDataEntryValue}): inputValues is RegisterFormFields {
    // do your validation and type checking here...
    if (!inputValues.myValue || typeof inputValues.myValue !== 'string') return false;
    return true;
  }

if (!validFormData(inputValues)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid form data')
}

// Here your inputValues now have type RegisterFormFields and are validated by you
console.log(inputValues);
```